# dynamic extra fields in django inlineformset

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset

i'm working on a projects for a mobile store which working with `IMEI` of mobiles each single mobile has its own imei , and the owner of the store selling phone depend on its IMEI's , now when the admin add new mobile in `MobileStorage` for example quantity= 20 mobile `iphone11X` have 20 different IMEI's , i want to allow the admin whenever he add new mobile and then select the quantities (20) then extra fields will be 20 , if he filled 10 in quantity field extra fields for IMEI will be 10

```
class MobileStorage(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobile = models.ForeignKey(Mobile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Imei(models.Model):
    imei = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name='IMEI',unique=True)
    mobile = models.ForeignKey(MobileStorage,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class Mobile(models.Model):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
```

my forms.py

```
class MobileStorageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    mobile = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Mobile.objects.all(),empty_label='')
    class Meta:
       model = MobileStorage
       fields = [
        'mobile','quantity'
       ]

class ImeiForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Imei
       fields = ['imei']
```

i want to control extra fields depend on the quantity in `MobileStorage` model , and the create for example 20 instance in `Imei` model

```
MobileStorageFormInlineSet = inlineformset_factory(
    MobileStorage,Imei,form=ImeiForm,fields=('imei'),extra=2,can_delete=False
)
```

i have done the front end , but it just save the last 2 fields bcs extra fields are 2

anyone have an idea i appreciate it

Comment: [Check this SO answer. You put it ins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14197846)

Comment: You can put the formset definition inside a function, [like this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14197846)

Answer (score -1):

Hey U can also use Jquery To add Field by click add or remove button in a front-end pages django

Comment: <script src="{% static '/jquery.formset.js' %}">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.formset_row-{{ formset.prefix }}').formset({
        addText: 'add another',
        deleteText: 'remove',
        prefix: '{{ formset.prefix }}',
    });
</script>

Comment: i did the front end , but it desnt save all , its just save 2 fields , bcs extra fields are 2